# Fitting a wide webpage to the width of mobile device

Tags: android, iphone, html, css

I have a site, which in order to fit the content of some of the pages, the min-width of the site is 1170px.  I also can't make a separate mobile version.

IPhones and Droids usually automatically resize the page in order to fit the width.  However they seem to not resize the page if the height of the content is less than the height of the screen and then the width runs off screen.

Any ideas of what I should change? I don't know what edits to make that won't mess up the desktop presentation.

Comment: add <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> in html page

Comment: @Tamil Selvan Thank you but I tried that and it's actually making the page load even further off.  Maybe it's conflicting with my other css?  Here's an example page: http://www.pactlegacy.com/site/contactus.php

Answer (score 4):

There are some way to do it the very important before anything else

if you target to work on in the devices just put that code before end tag of `</head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

then if you dont want to repeat your code just target the screen you want your website display using [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

example below:

```
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 320px){
    .yourElementClassOrId {
        width:100%;  
    }
} 

@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 720px){
    .yourElementClassOrId {
        width:100%;  
    }
}  
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 620px){
    .yourElementClassOrId {
        width:100%;  
    }
}
```

but it easy to manipulate your site if your site already have [flexible grid](http://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids&ei=s59vUde7OuXniAeFsYDIBQ&usg=AFQjCNEu_D7VaMAVCvSGq6eZ6nH-huMFBA&sig2=yvsgCdKL5c10sVh6wVIZ1A&bvm=bv.45373924,d.aGc)

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` to the meta viewport. This is Android specific.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using twitter bootstrap, and **bootstrap-responsive.css** is missing in your code.